# Pad a regex capture group?

Tags: python, regex

Is there some way to pad single digit numbers with a 0 with regex?
I'm using Python.

Examples:

- 6 => 06
- 1 => 01

etc.

Here's what I'm working on: https://regex101.com/r/iG9qC7/1

I'd like all the file names to have a uniform format.

Comment: Use [capturing groups and back references](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html). Are you trying to bulk rename files? May I suggest using an application designed for that? The `ranger` file manager has a command called bulkrename (type `:bulkrename`) that opens vim (or your favorite editor) with all the files in the current folder (or selected files with `:bulkrename %s`). Then you can use the text substitution feature from your editor to rename the filenames -- close the editor and the files get renamed. Vim supports regular expressions, so you could use `%s/\(\d\)/0\1/g` or similar.

Comment: No, I'm using flexget and trying to manipulate the file names when they're written initially. Thanks for the tip on `ranger`. I'll check it out.

Comment: So you want the *result* to be padded with zeroes? If so, look at printf, printf("%02d", i) will print i at least two digits long and padded with zeroes. I don't know if this is doable in a regular regex replace in python, it is in perl and JavaScript, but I don't think python.

Answer (score 2):

## [Success when read docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

This just uses the regex substitution function and the `zfill` string function to pad inside of a callback function.

```
import re

a = """Hello 1 of 60
Hello.22.of.60.
Hello 33of60
Hello.44of60.
Hello 1 of 6
Hello.2.of.6.
Hello 3of6
Hello.04of6.""".splitlines()

def F(m):return r' S01E%s'%m.group(1).zfill(2)
print '\n'.join([re.sub(r'\D(\d+).*', F, x, 1)for x in a])
```

Output:

```
Hello S01E01
Hello S01E22
Hello S01E33
Hello S01E44
Hello S01E01
Hello S01E02
Hello S01E03
Hello S01E04
```

Or if you want to keep the second number, a slight difference:

```
print '\n'.join([re.sub(r'\D(\d+).*?(\d+).*', lambda m:r' S01E%s of %s'%(m.group(1).zfill(2),m.group(2).zfill(2)), x)for x in a])
```

Output:

```
Hello S01E01 of 60
Hello S01E22 of 60
Hello S01E33 of 60
Hello S01E44 of 60
Hello S01E01 of 06
Hello S01E02 of 06
Hello S01E03 of 06
Hello S01E04 of 06
```